# Amp pages, PWA and mobile website

Tags: amp-html, progressive-web-apps

this in not a very technical question.
I have and editorial website, and my website is not responsive. 
I have a desktop version and a mobile versione created using Rails Variants, so for mobile I'm using a lightest layout with a unique design.

I need to add amp pages, and I already add the amp version to every content. Now with Progressive Web App I think that offline contents, push notification and "app feeling" could enhance the user experience.

Is possibile to have a configuration like this:

- Desktop -> desktop versione
- Smartphone -> mobile layout
- Google News -> amp pages
- Android smartphone with site added as app - > PWA with amp pages

Answer (score 0):

Probably not just Google News would hit your AMP pages - they appear in search results for normal searches on mobile too. After first hitting the AMP page, the second page the user clicks on would normally be your mobile site version of your content (although there is nothing stopping you keeping your users in the AMP site except subsequent pages will not be served from the amp cache).

You can add PWA features to your AMP pages so there is no difference between your point 3 and 4.

Also you can build a non-amp PWA (as you suggest) that shows your amp content:

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/pwa-amp/amp-in-pwa